# How to center text inside the mat-toolbar using flex layout?

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I need to create a footer with 2 simple rows the company name and the year. Here is my html snippet,

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="height: 176px">
  <span>Company name</span>
  <span>Copyright ©2019</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

So that company name has to be at the center (vertically and horizontally) and the copyright should be below of the company name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just place the `spans` into a `mat-toolbar-row`. They are basically made for structuring content in lines.

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span class="span">First Line</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span class="span">Second Line</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Then you just have to center the `spans`.

```
.span {
    margin: auto;
}
```